# Why does Mirror's Edge go choppy and unplayable on occasion?

Tags: mirrors-edge

When playing Mirrors Edge the framerate drops until it is unplayable and runs at 1-2 FPS. At all other times it's fine, and opening to the main menu and resuming resolves the issue, as does quitting and then returning back to the game. The most recent time is when I've got to Ropeburns Office and I'm climbing up the waterfalls, I jump across to the balconies and when I get shot at the frames drop to next to nothing.

I'm running on a quad-core AMD 2.8Ghz with 8GB of RAM from a OCZ SSD and a ATI Radeon 7870 Core graphics card. I didn't have any issues when playing on my laptop - Dual core 2.0Ghz Intel with 4GB RAM and integrated graphics.

Comment: sounds like there's something else going on with your desktop that's the issue, maybe a background process?  Does this happen with any other games?

Comment: It's just Mirror's Edge I've noticed the fault with.

Comment: Yes, when Faith is being shot at there is a *lot* of breaking glass.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's likely to be an issue with NVidia's PhysX engine. I had a look around and it's noticed that PhysX does not play well with a lot of ATI graphics cards.

Comment: The problem isn't that PhysX doesn't play well *with* ATI/AMD cards, but rather that PhysX does not *run on* AMD cards at all. So with Nvidia GPUs you get GPU-accelerated PhysX while on AMD and Intel GPUs the fabric physics are computed on the CPU, which is awfully slow.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and after a bit of searching I found that this works on my XFX radeon 6870 card.

go to options > video > and disable PhysX