# Strange lag in Mirror's edge

Tags: pc, windows-10, mirrors-edge

I was trying to play Mirror's Edge on my new Win 10 Laptop with
1. i5 6200 2.3 GHz
2. 4 GB GeForce 940M
3. 8 GB RAM
The game was running on highest settings, res 1366x768.

The game runs just fine, until there is a chase, and then the game goes extremely choppy, its like tearing between the frames, but I have vsync on, the game seems to run smoothly, maybe some frames get skipped or something like that. I can run FIFA 13, NFS Most Wanted 2012 edition, Dead Island and Assassin's creed on highest settings without any problems. Also my PC specs are well above the required ones so theoretically it should run fine.

Is it some problem with the game or with my PC?

Comment: @Timelord64 Whoa buddy are you saying that a 4GB GeForce 940M is **NOT ENOUGH** to run Mirror's edge? Then how come it can run games that demand significantly more graphical processing power? My PC is not at all short of specifications of running the game.

Comment: @Timelord64 and that's 4GB of VRAM not 2

Comment: @Timelord64 Moreover the game runs smoothly on a rooftop chase (where there is smoke, buildings, obstacle plus people shooting at me) and then lags in a nearly empty room. Doesn't make any sense... There's no point in putting this question on hold.

Comment: I learnt the hard way that judging a card entirely off its VRAM leads to these very problems. If you care to look at the link I provided, you will notice the comparison takes many capabilities into account, all of which a 940m model comes up trumps. Alternativley, if you can link to your model (again, a 940m advertises as a 2G), we can explore further.

Comment: also, the minimum card advertises 16GB.

Comment: Turn off Pysx in the settings. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121633/why-does-mirrors-edge-go-choppy-and-unplayable-on-occasion

Comment: Wow.. I apologise completely. I had misinterpretted this as asking about the new mirrors edge (for some reason).

Comment: Try the solution suggested by @Burgi, but bear in mind that the solution deliberetly details ATI cards, and the solution is effectivley made redundant by using an nVidia card.

Comment: @Timelord64 With Nvidia cards you have to specify the PsyX processor in the Nvidia control panel. In some instances it will default to the CPU. There are several forum threads on it but a comment is not the place to discuss them.

Comment: @Timelord64 I did mention in my post that it is _an old game_ anyways no prob, that explains why you were mad at me putting my question on hold. :P So Now can it be removed from hold? I want to answer it and help anyone else who comes up.

Comment: @Burgi I already did that, I actually came back only to post results... Turn off physx and the game runs just fine. I couldn't however make out any differences in graphics look after turning physx off. What does it actually do?

Comment: other users voted to put it on hold, just waiting for another reopen vote and it should open.

Comment: We should take this to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39623/mirrors-edge-psyx).

Comment: If there is "tearing" then vsync cannot be on. Tearing is the result of the screen being updated out of sync with the refresh rate and you see partial multiple frames at once. Vsync forces the rendering to wait until the sync wait state to change out the image. If the renderer cannot draw as fast or faster than the refresh rate, then it must wait and the effective FPS is halved. So instead of going from 60 to 58 to 50 to 55 to 60, you get 60 to 30 to 30 to 30 to 60. This large cliff-like drop if a lot more noticeable and most people call this choppy.

Comment: @Yorik thanks for the explanation... I just called that tearing, actually I couldn't think of any other way of expressing that kind of lag :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned off physx and now it runs fine...

Comment: Exactly the same happens on Batman Arkham Asylum with physx turned on.